# How to create a Dictionary from an Array that will generate repeated keys

Tags: c#

I have an array that I want to convert to a dictionary by splitting the array values from the equal sign (`=`). The content before the equal sign will be the key and the content after it will be the value. My issue is that some values from the array will have the same key name when splitting it and adding them to the dictionary.

Here is what I have...

```
string[] myArray = new[] { "A=1", "B=2", "C=3", "A=4" };
Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = myArray.Select(l => l.Split('=')).ToDictionary(a => a[0], a => a[1]);
```

As expected, I get error: `ArgumentException was unhandled by user code` since the first and the last value will have the same keys.

What I would like to be able to do is exclude/ignore the values that will generate duplicate keys. In other words, based on my code I don't want to add the value `A=4` to my dictionary.

Any idea what would be the best way to accomplish this?

FYI - My code works fine if I remove the last value from the array.

Comment: Just use a regular foreach loop and check if the dictionary .ContainsKey() before adding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `GroupBy` before `ToDictionary`:

```
var result = myArray.Select(s => s.Split('='))
                    .GroupBy(a => a[0])
                    .ToDictionary(e => e.Key,
                             v => v.Select(a => a[1]).First());
```

or iterating and checking if the key is not contained in the result dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, string> accumulator = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var item in myArray.Select(x => x.Split('=')))
       if (!accumulator.ContainsKey(item[0]))
           accumulator.Add(item[0], item[1]);
```

Comment: Your first example worked fine with one exception, when the array contains two values with the same name but one is in lower case and the other in upper case it adds the two values to the Dictionary.  `string[] myArray = new[] { "A=1", "B=2", "C=3", "a=4" }` in this example the first and the last values will be added to the dictionary even though they have the same name. Is there a way to ignore case type to make sure it see them as the same name so it adds only one?

Comment: @fs_tigre sure, just change the `.GroupBy(a => a[0])` to `.GroupBy(a => a[0].ToLower())`

Answer (score 1):

You may use GroupBy , and group the splitted values by it's first value (index 0), and then get first of each group (ignore others with same value in the index 0):

```
  var  myArray.Select(l => l.Split('=')).GroupBy(x=>x[0]).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault());
```

Or just do the ignore part when adding to Dictionary:

```
foreach(string[] x in  myArray.Select(l => l.Split('=')).ToArray())
{
     if(!Dic.ContainsKey(x[0]))Dic.Add(x[0], x[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, which converts the given array to unique dictionary. The `GroupBy`, groups the data based on left side of Key and later `ToDictionary` converts the fetched grouped result to dictionary.

```
 Dictionary<string, string> myDictionary = myArray.Select(l => 
     { 
        var splittedStrings = l.Split('=');
        return new { Key = splittedStrings[0], Val = splittedStrings[1] };
      }).GroupBy(g => g.Key)
     .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.First().Val);
```